# Does Logitech unifying nano receiver perform keyboard input encryption?

Tags: logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

If I pair Logitech unifying nano receiver with wireless Logitech keyboard (that support unifying technology), will typed information transmitted by air ciphered with *128-bit Keyboard Encryption*?

Comment: Even if there is 128 bit encryption using a well established algorithm, there is probably still one weak spot: Key generation and exchange. "Strong" encryption can only be strong with a good random key. And you certainly cannot rely on manufacturers to use good keys. Just remind of Arcadyan, where some probably brain-dead developers invented and patented(!) an algorithm to deterministically derive the default WPA passphrase from the MAC address. So you might in fact want to ask, if there is strong encryption.

Comment: Keys are not random, as I know. Logitech says that they use a secret algorithm of selection of new encryption key due pairing process on device and receiver. Also I know that key is stored in receiver's memory, not in OS. I believe that this encryption and key policy is enough for me - it is not so easy as RAW transfer or XOR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Logitech Unifying Q&A for the IT Manager or Business Manager](https://www.logitech.com/images/pdf/roem/Unifying_QA_IT_business_managers_7709_EMEA.pdf) states:

> **What wireless technology is integrated with Unifying peripherals?**
>
> Logitech Advanced 2.4 GHz is integrated into all compatible devices,
>   and provides 128-bit AES encryption between keyboard and receiver.

For more see: [Logitech Whitepaper: Logitech Advanced 2.4 GHz Technology
With Unifying Technology (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160516054812/https://www.logitech.com/images/pdf/roem/Advanced_24_Unifying_FINAL070709.pdf)^

^Last accessible on 16 May 2016 via the Internet Archive

Comment: So, the answer is **“Yes”**. *Unifying QA* document is exactly what I needed to be sure. Thank you.

Comment: Is this still the case for non-business Unifying? All of these white papers (on google) specifiy only Logitech FOR BUSINESS.

Comment: The white paper is written for such persons but as Logitech doesn't make different consumer/business versions of their devices, so the statements should apply to all Unifying devices.

Comment: I wonder if the USB protocol itself is encrypted. Can the dongle communicate with a Linux OS without risk of hardware keylogging? Or would the motherboard or other HW or non-open SW components have access to the raw data?